# How to change read/write permissions of a user uploaded file ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm writing an ASP.NET webform (using the VS 2017 template) to allow a user to upload a file, then download a copy of that file restricted to read only access. I had no problem doing something analogous to this in a desktop app (by changing FileInfo.IsReadOnly to false) but it doesn't seem like I can apply that solution with web forms.

I've tried this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_file_uploading.htm

however, I don't want to save the file anywhere on the server, I just want to download the restricted file immediately.

Comment: Download it to where?  The user's (who just uploaded the file) computer?  If that's the case, it will never work (you can't control file permissions on a remote computer through HTTP).  Why would you need to do this anyway?

Comment: Yes, I'd be downloading it to the user's computer. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I do not understand where is your issue - you make a handler that download files, they can not change it, neither delete it -

Comment: @Becuzz I want to create a read-only copy of the file on the server, then download.

Comment: @Othan Are you trying to make it so the downloaded file can't be edited or something?  Because that's impossible.  I don't the point in trying to make the file read only on the server.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do. I don't understand why I can't control file permissions over HTTP - can you point me to any resources about that?